# DPRP is disabled for this merchant in Sandbox Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Trying to Created Billing Agreement in PayPal with Sandbox Account with REST API.
But getting error DPRP is disabled for this merchant. Also try with enable business account to PRO.

Thanks in Advance.